# Why can't I include images in pdf using Pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

I can successfully produce the images when output is HTML, but errors out when attempting pdf output.

#### input file text for image,

```
  ![](images\icon.png "test")
```

#### Error produced,

> pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
>   ! Undefined control sequence.
>    images\icon
>
> l.535 \includegraphics{images\icon.png}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Note that pandoc produces the PDF via LaTeX, as the error message reveals.  Your input

```
![](images\icon.png "test")
```

is converted into LaTeX

```
\includegraphics{images\icon.png}
```

`\` in LaTeX has a special meaning: it begins a control sequence. So LaTeX is looking for an `\icon` command here and not finding it.  The fix is to use a forward slash `/` instead of a backslash `\` as path separator.  [LaTeX allows you to use `/` for paths even in Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/paths-and-linux-windows-slash-conventions).

Of course, this may cause problems in some other output formats.  I suppose I should change pandoc to convert backslashes in paths to forward slashes when writing LaTeX.

Comment: Note, if you include other pdf pages as images, then it breaks Adobe reader with error 131. e.g. ![My image](pretty.pdf) causes Adobe reader 9.5.5 in any event. Note that other readers work fine though.

Comment: not sure whether this would deserver a separate post, but any thoughts why inserting a link to an image also doesn't work?

Comment: In addition, import are always relative to the working directory, and not to the file itself, unless we use `markdown+rebase_relative_paths`.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem on Windows. My images are stored in a subdirectory named "figures". No matter what I tried the path wasn't followed. I have solved it by including `--resource-path=.;figures` in the call to pandoc.

Comment: --resource-path=.:figures on Linux